# WSO2 DAS performance slowly deteriorates

Tags: wso2, wso2-das

We're running DAS 3.1.0 together with our API Manager 1.10.0 from where we send events. The events are received in a receiver at DAS, sent to a stream, then handled by an execution plan and the outcome is sent out to two publishers, sending the data to an RDBMS. The number of events to DAS is around 30-40 events / second.

When first initiated, the DAS is able to output events to the RDBMS in real-time, but we can notice it very slowly starting to "fall behind". After an hour or so, the "lag" is maybe 15-30 seconds, after a few hours the "lag" is around 20 minutes behind and after 4-5 hours, there's no events handled anymore (we can see it doesn't store any data in its incoming events database at this point).

The DAS is still up and running, end there are no error logs anywhere-- but we obviously want it to keep outputting data in real-time, not with an exponential "back-off"-multiplier which seems to be the case.

Could there be any remedy for this in terms of settings? Could it be an accumulating memory-problem somehow? (attaching some outputs of memory-usage). We can see memory starts to accumulate over time, so we tried changing the JVM settings to optimize:

```
-Xms3072m -Xmx3072m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:NewSize=256m -XX:MaxNewSize=614m -XX:SurvivorRatio=10 -XX:-DisableExplicitGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:+AggressiveOpts -XX:+UseStringCache -XX:+OptimizeStringConcat
```

We also tried changing some performance settings which made it at least "last longer", but still the same outcome:

**Data-bridge-config.xml:**

```
<workerThreads>3</workerThreads>

<maxEventBufferCapacity>1</maxEventBufferCapacity>

<eventBufferSize>2000</eventBufferSize>

<clientTimeoutMin>30</clientTimeoutMin>
```

**Data-agent-config.xml:**

```
<QueueSize>1024</QueueSize>
<BatchSize>100</BatchSize>
<CorePoolSize>2</CorePoolSize>
<SocketTimeoutMS>30000</SocketTimeoutMS>
<MaxPoolSize>2</MaxPoolSize>
<KeepAliveTimeInPool>20</KeepAliveTimeInPool>
<ReconnectionInterval>30</ReconnectionInterval>
<MaxTransportPoolSize>250</MaxTransportPoolSize>
<MaxIdleConnections>250</MaxIdleConnections>
<EvictionTimePeriod>5500</EvictionTimePeriod>
<MinIdleTimeInPool>5000</MinIdleTimeInPool>
<SecureMaxTransportPoolSize>250</SecureMaxTransportPoolSize>
<SecureMaxIdleConnections>250</SecureMaxIdleConnections>
<SecureEvictionTimePeriod>5500</SecureEvictionTimePeriod>
<SecureMinIdleTimeInPool>5000</SecureMinIdleTimeInPool>
```

**Analytics-event-sink-config.xml:**

```
<QueueSize>1024</QueueSize>

<maxQueueCapacity>1</maxQueueCapacity>

<maxBatchSize>128</maxBatchSize>

<WorkerPoolSize>5</WorkerPoolSize>
```

Which sadly didn't help. Any hints or tips are much appreciated.

[image: Memory usage. Server was restarted at 3PM, 8PM and 7.40AM because it was lagging too far behind]

Memory usage. Server was restarted at 3PM, 8PM and 7.40AM because it was lagging too far behind.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your settings are a bit different than DAS recommendations. Please follow [DAS performance tuning guide](https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS310/Performance+Tuning) and see if you get any improvements.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. We've tried the different options at the performance tuning guide, none of them had any change in behavior sadly. As stated, when we tuned the options as above, we at least "lasted" longer-- but still same long term behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the database write performance in this case. For example, in some database servers, when records have blob fields, when the number of records grow, the insertion speed becomes slower (DAS analytics tables uses a blob field to encode and store field values). So it's best to profile the database operations and see if those are actually slow. And after that, you may want to do DBMS specific optmizations to make the performance better for blog storage.

Cheers,
Anjana.

Comment: Some further information. We've tested and concluded that the problem is in handling incoming events. The events doesn't show up in the receiver of our DAS when the problem starts (without huge lag). Also, when the performance has deteriorated, there's no way to "recover" from it without restarting it. No matter if it handles any events for a day, and we purge all events in the DAS database, there's still a huge lag before incoming events show up as received events. Does this give any further clue?